# Home network troubleshooting advice needed

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, troubleshooting

I'm having some trouble with my home network, and I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting... my ISP is Spectrum, and I have a 100Mbps connection.  Running speedtest shows this is pretty close to the speeds I really get.  Connected directly to the cable outlet is a netgear CM700, and connected to that is a Netgear Orbi Wifi system (RBR50).

The problem I'm experiencing is that devices connected to the Orbi will occasionally lose internet.  I take a lot of skype/chime calls on my iPhone over wifi at home and it pukes at least once an hour, and the only way to get back on is to disable wifi on the phone.  I also have several computers connected to the Orbi wifi, and these will lose internet connection at the same time.  It comes back rather quickly but it still drops.  Another bit of evidence is that the Orbi light ring goes magenta on occasion (although I've never seen this when I experience a connection issue, but I may have missed it).  The magenta indicates that the internet is down.

So the question is troubleshooting. It's either my ISP, but if I call them they will ask me to just work directly off the CM700 which isn't possible.  Netgear will tell me to check with my ISP.  I'd rather not go down that rat-hole of customer support and 100 level advice.

Is there any (free) software or something I can install that will help me monitor all my systems and give me some indication of where the failure is occurring?  At least then I would have some data... or is there something else I can do?

Comment: You could start by running `ping -t`from an end device to the WiFi device, the router, and to your ISP DNS server(s). If you get an outage that should tell you where the problem is.

Comment: A common cause of wifi dropouts is another nearby wifi with a similar signal strength on the same or a close channel. Most Android wifi managers can show whether this situation obtains for you.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is figure out if the problem is reaching your router or reaching the Internet from the router.

Comment: @DavidPostill This was a good suggestion... I ran ping and didn't get a response from my Orbi Wifi router.  I did get a response after a minute or two.  Only other question is if something else is killing my network every once in a while... bought the Orbi system in March of this year, so it shouldn't be dying yet.

Comment: @DavidPostill Can you post your response as an answer?  This was all I needed to figure it out.

Comment: @Nicros Answer added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I monitor my systems to get an indication of where the failure is occurring?

You can run `ping -t target` (ping the specified target until stopped) from an end device in your local network to the WiFi device, the router, and your ISP DNS server(s).

When you get an outage that will tell you where the problem is.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [ping](http://ss64.com/nt/ping.html) - Test a network connection - if successful, ping returns the ip address.

Comment: Thanks!  I found that when the network dropped I wasn't even able to ping my wifi router.  After doing some research, turns out that there was an automatic firmware upgrade that was... um... crap.  I reverted back to a previous version and everything worked perfectly.